# Selenium value finding trouble help probably beginner level

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello I am new to python and was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to get a value using selenium and some terminology in HTML to help future searches.

I am trying to take a value that changes from page to page out of a div tag and assign it to a value.

Here is the HTML I am searching:

```
<div class="order-progress-bar" data-current-step-index="4">
```

I am trying to get that 4 into a value to print, this is what I have so far:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'data-current-step-index')]")
print(element)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='order-progress-bar']")
print(elem.get_attribute("data-current-step-index"))
```

Get the element you want and print it's attribute. Also stop using driver.find_element_by_xpath it's depreciated.

You could also use  @data-current-step-index='4' if there are several or just wrap it (xpath)[index] and get a certain one.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```